# Batch rename extension to lowercase

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I can rename a folder of .TXT files to a lowercase extension with

```
ren *.TXT *.txt
```

But that's because I know the extension, of which there is only one. Is there a one liner for looping over a directory and changing all the extensions to lowercase?

I tried:

```
for %%f in (*.*) do (rename "%%f" "%%~xf")
```

That works...to some extent, but it also removes the filename part. D'oh!

Fail better.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/65302/is-there-a-way-to-batch-rename-files-to-lowercase (but it changed the whole filename to lower case)

Comment: You could use `*%%~xf` to get `*.txt` which would fix the rename command.  But I don;'t see how `%%~xf` gives you a lowercase version of the extension.  On my Win7 machine `%%~xf` returns the extension in the same case as the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /l "%sourcedir%\%%A" '
  ) DO (
  if "%%~xa" neq "%%~xA" ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%A" "%%~nA%%~xa"
)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Naturally, the two nested `for` commands may be compacted to a single line if desired - shown here on multiple lines for legibility.

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Note that `%%A` retains the original character-case but `%%a` (a completely *different* variable) acquires the lower-case equivalent because of the `/l` switch on the `dir` command.

---

Following Aacini's response, more extensive testing (well, actually trying to rename files rather than just generate a rename instruction that *should* on first glance work) revealed this doesn't actually work, possibly because the OS sees a file being renamed to its own name (disregarding case). Hmph.

So - first step was to rename twice - first to a dummy name, and then from the dummy name to the required name.

Fine in theory. Problem was that the `~x` operator doesn't seem to consistently report the same string - almost depending on how many times it's used. So - I tried executing a subroutine, passing the "to" and "from" filenames. The subroutine seemed to have the same problems when attempting to access the name fragments of the parameters. Gloom.

So I assigned the name to a variable and tried processing *that*. Repeatedly remove the string before `.` in the name until there are no more dots and you have the extension.

Then remove the extension from the filename, but can't use the replace-with-nothing method since the filename may be `whatever.txt.txt` for instance. So lop off the last few characters one at a time within a loop for the length of the extension found+1 (for the dot).

So - if the lower-case version of the extension found is the same as the current-case version in `ext2`, no rename required. Otherwise, rename to the original-case name+the lower-case extension. Via a dummy name to ensure the OS doesn't get too smart for itself.

And here's the result. Subject to unexpected results with the usual characters, of course.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
:choosedummy
SET "dummyname=dummyname.%random%"
IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%dummyname%" GOTO choosedummy

FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /l "%sourcedir%\%%A" '
  ) DO CALL :casechg "%%a" "%%A"
)

GOTO :EOF

:casechg
SET "ext2=%~2"
SET "name2=%~2"
:ext2loop
IF "%ext2%" neq "%ext2:*.=%" SET "ext2=%ext2:*.=%"&GOTO ext2loop

:: if extension cases are identical, or no extension, skip rename
IF "%~x1" equ "" GOTO :EOF 
IF "%~x1" equ ".%ext2%" GOTO :EOF 

SET "lop=%ext2%"
:loploop
SET "name2=%name2:~0,-1%"
IF DEFINED lop SET "lop=%lop:~1%"&GOTO loploop

REN "%sourcedir%\%~2" "%dummyname%"
REN "%sourcedir%\%dummyname%" "%name2%%~x1"
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: This method does not work in my Windows 8.1 computer. Although the `dir /b /l` command correctly show the file name in lowcase characters, the _original_ (upcase) extension is replaced in `%%~xa` part. I don't know if the same behavior happen in other Windows versions...

Comment: @Aacini: well, it *appeared* to create a correct-ish command under W10. Appearances can be deceptive. No doubt the OS thinks that it'll bypass any silly ideas like renaming a file to its current name, so no change took place when the `ren` was released....and that's where the story begins...

Answer (score 2):

It ***is*** possible with pure batch but clumsy.

I suggest using a PowerShell script wrapped in cmdline/batch for this:

```
powershell -nop -c "gci -file|ren -newname {$_.BaseName+($_.Extension.ToLower())}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add *two lines more* to your original code: **1.** Get the extension. **2.** Convert it to lowercase.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set "ext=%%~Xf"
   for %%c in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "ext=!ext:%%c=%%c!"
   ren "%%f" "%%~Nf!ext!"
)
```

**EDIT:** The new method below correctly manage the case when there are files with no extension. This method is also more efficient because it convert just one string to lowercase and execute a `ren` command per each extension instead of per each file. These are the steps: **1.** Get all *different* file extensions in a string. **2.** Convert this string to lowercase. **3.** Use each extension in this string to execute a `ren` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "exts= "
for %%f in (*.*) do if "!exts:%%~Xf=!" equ "!exts!" set "exts=!exts! %%~Xf"
for %%c in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "exts=!exts:%%c=%%c!"
for %%e in (%exts%) do ren "*%%e" "*%%e"
```

Comment: +1 Works great but fails on files that have **no** extension as it would add `a=a` to the name then. You should fix that with an if statement.

Comment: Nice solution works great! In my opinion the OP should accept this, but that's clearly left to him/her.